# In React, On clicking browser back button I should click one DOM ele(for instance, button) and should be in the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, frontend

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      document.getElementById('sample-button').click()
    })
```

which event listener should be added?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using class component like

```
class pp extends React.Component {

  //This method is called when a component is being removed from the DOM:
  componentWillUnmount()
  {
     document.getElementById('sample-button').click()
  }

  render(){
    return ...
}

}
```

Comment: Actually I should be in same Component and that button should be clicked.